# tf2_ros::Buffer.transform() causes "undefined reference" errors

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use `tf2_ros::Buffer.transform()` and when trying to compile I am getting "undefined reference" errors from the linker. I don't link I'm missing any libraries, because `tf2_ros::Buffer.lookupTransform()` compiles just fine and I added all possible tf2 libraries. Am I doing something wrong or does it seem to be a bug?

Below is the code of my test node and error messages. And my entire test package is at https://github.com/tommises/ros-tf2-issue

For what it's worth, `tf::TransformListener.transformPoint()` works fine as well. Is there any risk in mixing **tf** and **tf2**?

- ROS version: kinetic
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

---

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>
    
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h> 

tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;

void ellipsevsCallback(const geometry_msgs::PointStamped::ConstPtr& point_raw){
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
    transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("global", "local", ros::Time(0));
    
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped point_tf;
    /* This is the line which fails to compile. */
    tfBuffer.transform(*point_raw, point_tf, "local");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tf2_test_tf2_point");
    tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
    
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    ros::Subscriber topic_sub = node.subscribe("test/point", 1, &ellipsevsCallback);
    
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
};
```

linker errors

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable tf2_test_tf2_point
CMakeFiles/tf2_test_tf2_point.dir/src/tf2_test_tf2_point.cpp.o: In function `geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >& tf2_ros::BufferInterface::transform<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Duration) const':
tf2_test_tf2_point.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE]+0x69): undefined reference to `ros::Time const& tf2::getTimestamp<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
tf2_test_tf2_point.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE]+0x7b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const& tf2::getFrameId<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
tf2_test_tf2_point.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE]+0xc8): undefined reference to `void tf2::doTransform<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&, geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tf2_test/CMakeFiles/tf2_test_tf2_point.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'tf2_test/tf2_test_tf2_point' failed
make[2]: *** [tf2_test/tf2_test_tf2_point] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1340: recipe for target 'tf2_test/CMakeFiles/tf2_test_tf2_point.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tf2_test/CMakeFiles/tf2_test_tf2_point.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

and my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(tf2_test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  tf2
  tf2_bullet
  tf2_eigen
  tf2_geometry_msgs
  tf2_kdl
  tf2_msgs
  tf2_py
  tf2_ros
  tf2_sensor_msgs
  tf2_tools
  tf
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(tf2_test_tf2_point src/tf2_test_tf2_point.cpp)
add_executable(tf2_test_tf1_point src/tf2_test_tf1_point.cpp)

target_link_libraries(tf2_test_tf2_point
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
target_link_libraries(tf2_test_tf1_point
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239260/tf2_ros::buffer.transform()-causes-%22undefined-reference%22-errors/) by [tommises](https://answers.ros.org/users/27449/tommises/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h"

You can look at this tutorial :
http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Using%20stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf2%3A%3AMessageFilter

---

Originally posted by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) with karma: 365 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [veggiebenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/35814/veggiebenz/) on 2018-09-11**:
This was helpful -- but for me the problem was that I did not have the packages in CMakeLists.txt.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

**Comment by [Kapcirt](https://answers.ros.org/users/34723/kapcirt/) on 2018-12-24**:
Hello veggiebenz, I encounter the same issue. Which packages did you needed to add in the CMakeLists.txt ?

**Comment by [liyxhit](https://answers.ros.org/users/53259/liyxhit/) on 2020-04-05**:
I add tf2 and tf2_ros to the find_package to solve this problem

**Comment by [DC pig](https://answers.ros.org/users/90322/dc-pig/) on 2022-04-24**:
The solution is still valid until foxy. So, why is the tf2_geometry_msg essential here? The code doesn't use the lib directly. If there is indirectly use, the corresponding file should include the lib...

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-04-25**:
The `transform` method is uses templated methods on the type T. If you pass in the datatype `geometry_msgs::PointStamped` you also need to make sure to provide the templated converter methods to allow `transform` to operate on the datatype. The underlying "library" does not know about any datatypes except it's internal forms and is specifically designed not to know about any alternative datatypes. This design allows you to pass in any datatype and as long as you provide the templated conversion functions the library can operate on your custom datatype in your code without adding a dependency into the underlying library on your custom datatype.

**Comment by [DC pig](https://answers.ros.org/users/90322/dc-pig/) on 2022-04-25**:
3q so much!